# How to tap and hold an Image in CarouselView Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, view, carousel

I have added carouselview with amazing animation using this library: https://github.com/sayyam/carouselview. The problem is i dont know how to stop the animation or movement of carousel images when the image is holded.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

this libbrary has function called setautoplay  make it  false
like carouselview.setautoplay(false);

Comment: No that i found before already, it will stop autoplay, i just want to stop it when user holds it, and then let it start automatically again, i am thinking to add touch handlers for each image and then set autoplay false when touched and set autoplay true again when leaves, but looking for a shorter or better approach here.

Comment: really?   CV.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) { carouselview.setautoplay(false);
                return false;
            }
        });